# Regexp find url that may contains space

Tags: regex

I am extracting some text from websites that contains some url.

The url may contains some space that I want the regexp to be able to identify.

Here is my regexp that I found

`\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,\.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]`

If we follow the text below

```
Sample text for testing:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 +-.,!@#$%^&*();\\/|<>\"\'
12345 -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
555.123.4567    +1-(800)-555-2468
foo@demo.net    bar.ba@test.co.uk
www.de mo.com   http://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
fa moo moo.com fa moo moo.co.uk da moo[dot]com doo moo [dot] com and not moo.c0m but do moo.cc and moo.co0uk
www.example.com/hello.html?ho#t-t_hy sdf http://regexr.com/ sdflkjlkjsdf sjkdhfkhsdf kjshdf
https://loca lhost:5000/#/tl/myteam  
www.home4.com
http://localhost:5000

www.d em m.com for visiting. People no longer wore their thick coats and cotton-padded jackets. They regained their spirits like before.
```

I want the matches result to be as follows:

```
www.home4.
www.example.com/hello.
www.de mo.
http://regexr.
http://foo.co.
www.d em m.
```

The solution could be other then regex, it make no difference to me.

### Update

Here is the updated version that worked for me, but I am failing to get the last url (`www.d em m.`)

`(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,\.| ]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$](\.)`
`

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're dealing with malformed data. I suggest you fix the data rather than create a complicated regex that accommodates it. There's almost no way to recognize something like `https://loca lhost:5000` or `www.de mo.com` as URLs without possibly including false positives.

Comment: I am not wanting `moo.co.uk` it has to start with a valid start. ``http|https|www.` and end with a valid end to

Comment: What is a "valid end" for you?? Do you want to pack IANAs [list of top level domains](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) into a regex? (At the time when I post this, the list counts 1482 TLDs, "localhost" not included...)

Comment: I also don't see why your wanted result cuts off after the last dot? (like `www.home4.` when the text contains `www.home4.com`). Please either add it as a requirment to your question or edit the wanted parts to at least contain the full URL for the valid stuff.

Answer (score 0):

@Alen.Toma, try this regex

`(?miU)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)\:\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:[\-A-Z0-9\+\&\@\\\/%\=~_\|\$\?\!\:,\.]*)(?:(?:\ +[A-Z0-9\+\&\@\\\/%\=~_\|\$\!\:,\. ]+(?:\.com|\#\S+\s|\.|$|\s\s))|\.$|\.\s\s|\.\s$|\.\s\S)`

see [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/S0TW9).

(Whole result:

```
www.de mo.com
http://regexr.com/ sdflkjlkjsdf sjkdhfkhsdf kjshdf
https://loca lhost:5000/#/tl/myteam 
www.d em m.com
www.home4.
www.example.com/hello.
www.de mo.
http://regexr.
http://foo.co.
https://regexr.
https://foo.co.
www.d em m.
```

)

Here is the only problem with `http://regexr.com/ sdflkjlkjsdf sjkdhfkhsdf kjshdf`. In fact, there is no clear end of unvalid url definition, in your question. So, `http://regexr.com/ sdflkjlkjsdf sjkdhfkhsdf kjshdf` could be good url (but with inserted spaces). More, there could be another proper urls with spaces, like `www.example.com/hello.html?ho#t-t_hy sdf` - as said @CAustion, there is almost no way to recognize all of them clearly.